# Facebook signup is not working in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am developing a mobile application using ionic framework.I have added [cordova plugin facebook](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4) for facebook signup.This feature is working perfectly in android version.
But in ios ,i am an getting an error **"There was a problem logging you in"** .But the login is working for some facebook accounts.

Ionic info

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v7.5.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
```